# Une nuance entre « se devait de » et « devait »

Tags: sens

> Il pensait qu'il **se devait de** devenir soldat.
>
> Il pensait qu'il **devait** devenir soldat.

Je m'interroge sur la différence de sens entre les deux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le [TLFI](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/devoir) indique clairement la différence:

> ***Devoir + inf.*** a une valeur modale; devoir explicite une nécessité plus ou moins pressante à laquelle sont soumis et l'agent d'un procès et le procès lui-même

« Il devait devenir soldat » → Il était nécessaire qu'il devienne soldat.

> ***Se devoir + de + inf.*** Pour désigner ce que l'on se croit tenu d'accomplir en vertu de la morale ou de l'usage

« Il se devait de devenir soldat » → Il pensait qu'il n'avait pas d'autre choix que de devenir soldat.

Comment: Alors, « devoir » indique qu'un facteur extérieur nous pousse à devenir soldat, alors que « se devoir de » s'emploie quand un sentiment personnel nous y incite ? Merci.

Comment: En général mais pas forcément : avec « je dois dormir » le facteur extérieur est quand même personnel. « Je me dois de dormir » → que j'aie sommeil ou pas, il faut quand même que je dorme.

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais que **se devait** connote un "pour bien faire" alors que **devait** est plus explicitement une obligation.